# slot into curved pipe

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a curved pipe.  This pipe will ultimately be fabricated as a thin-wall stainless steel pipe.  The pipe will be approximately 4" in diameter and 6' long.  I would like to know how to cut a slot 1" wide the full length of the pipe and keep the same exact curve.  Also, the curved pipe does not curve uniformly, it has a decreasing radius as you move to the two ends of the pipe.

Here is a top and side view of the pipe:

[image]

Comment: you could make it with a curve, then convert to mesh, duplicate one of the edge on its length, give it thickness then use it as a boolean object to create a slop on the pipe. But maybe show a drawing of what you mean because I may be wrong about what you mean...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, I created this curved pipe within the first hour of ever using software like Blender.  Absolute newbie, so I have no clue what you are explaining when you say "mesh", "boolean object" LOL.

Comment: Here is a top and side view of the pipe:  https://photos.app.goo.gl/GghtkmBjcywdAkrP7

Comment: did you create your pipe with a bezier curve? does the slot cut a hole in your pipe or just a groove?

Comment: Yes to bezier curve.  See the end view - white circle with slot cutout of the pipe in the linked image:  https://photos.app.goo.gl/aaeWak6Emr4z6UxV7

Comment: The idea is that there will be a wheel or roller inside the pipe with as stud coming up through the slot where it will attach to a handle.  The slot will allow the wheel/roller to be moved from one end of the pipe to the other.

Answer (score 2):

So what you could do is:

- First duplicate your curve to keep a safe copy somewhere. Now give it enough resolution, you'll have to make some tests but your mesh seems already smooth.

[image]

- Convert your curve to mesh (header menu > *Object* > *Convert To*)

[image]

- Select the edge where you want the slot to be, bevel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, delete the faces, you have your slot.

[image]

- Give your pipe a *Solidify* modifier to give it thickness, apply the modifier if your object is supposed to be printed at the end.

[image]

- To have an even smoother object you need to add geometry with the *Subdivision Surface* modifier. As it will round the corners you need to add edge loops to sharp them. Again, apply your modifier if the object is supposed to be printed at the end.

[image]

Comment: These are awesome instructions; however, after doing the conver to, no mesh appeared.  ctrl-B (command on Mac for me) didn't do anything.  I am using the latest version of Blender.

Comment: I'm on Mac and it should be ctrl by default, once you've made ctrl B then drag to scale the bevel and/or use the operator box on the bottom left of the 3D View

Comment: my email is jpgaber at gmail.  Can you email me.  I'd like to see if you can provide more direct support on this project as a contractor.